# Qt, C++ Draw Connector line between 2 Objects

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a line between two rectangles dynamically using mouseClick on QGraphicsScene. The line cant be slant. Each line segment of the line has to perpendicular to each other like the Elbow connector in PowerPoint.

The line should re-align itself automatically while drawing the line if the mouse goes in a slant direction.

Incase of QGraphicsLineItem drawing on scene, it can just be 1 straight line. I managed to do this but was unable to split to into 2 or more line segments. So how do I implement this?

[image]

Comment: The term you're looking for is *polyline*. The one shown in the image is a polyline with three line segments.

Comment: Have you actually checked what's already out there. Plenty of tutorials out there including (if I'm not mistaken) one in the Qt documentation itself with a diagram tool.

Comment: Ok polyline it is. How to go about it..Any suggestions?

Comment: You can show your code for reference

Comment: Drawing a polyLine dynamically is what I am not able to go about. Using a QGraphicsLineItem, I am able to draw just a single straight line dynamically with mouseMoveEvent. If I am not wrong, I cant construct a polyLine using a QGraphicsLineItem.. right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should roll out your own `QGraphicsItem` with a custom paint function.

It should be rather straightforward, the item will be a rectangle from the connection point of object A to the connection point of object B.

[image]

Inside this rectangle you draw 3 lines, one from its top left to top center, one from top center to bottom center, and another one from bottom center to bottom right.

Comment: I think the general solution is correct, although some cases should be considered: if the rectangle is _right-to-left_ then line must go from right-top to top center and so on... may instead of using the corners of the rectangle, the original points can be used: `{<src_x, src_y>, <rect.center().x(), src_y>, <rect.center().x(), dst_y>, <dst_x, dst_y>}`. It can be done in an analog way if the first line must be vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: The solution was for the OP particular scenario. It will definitely take a bit more logic than this to connect the items in an arbitrary position configuration.